# How to run a script every 5 seconds only when connected to internet

Tags: systemd, internet, systemd-timer

I have a script that updates my google drive.  I made a systemd unit to run this script, and a timer that runs the unit every 10 seconds, which both work.  However, when I get disconnected from internet, the script fails and systemd stops running the  it even if the internet comes back on.  Is there any way I can make systemd keep on running the script, or is there a way to have systemd run the script only if there is an internet connection?

Here are the files

/etc/systemd/system/grive.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Syncronize google drive folder

[Service]
User=my_name
ExecStart=/home/my_name/bin/update-grive
```

/etc/systemd/system/grive.timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for how often to syncronize google drive folder

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=10s
OnBootSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

/home/my_name/bin/update-grive:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /home/my_name/gdrive
grive
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `Restart=always` to the service unit, so systemd will keep bringing up the service if it crashes.

On a side note you should use `OnUnitInactiveSec` instead of `OnUnitActiveSec`.

`OnUnitInactiveSec=10s` (or 20s) will start the service 10 seconds after it stopped. This way you make sure it doesn't get called twice and possibly avoid banning for DOSing google

Comment: Wouldn't the script still fail if ping didn't work.  It would say unknown service google.com and return an error code right?

Comment: Nope. Run this oneliner in you shell to see it for yourself: `ping -c3 -q asdfgasdfg.com; if [ $? != 0 ]; then echo "failed but still here"; fi`. If the script failed as you suggest, the `echo` statement would not run

Comment: I tried something like that using racket, it printed the stuff after the failed ping, but systemd still counted it as failed.  It must be different in bash or something, I'll try it on my linux machine as soon as I can.

Comment: You need space around the brackets, and it still fails when there is no internet.

Comment: However, your `Restart=always` works.  I can accept the question if you delete the part about adding ping, or replace it with something that works.

Comment: @Vityou Edited. I didn't expect systemd to catch the retun code of the ping inside of the script. I'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to set the accuracy to seconds, like this:

```
AccuracySec=1s
```

As per the docs:

> AccuracySec=
> Specify the accuracy the timer shall elapse with.
> Defaults to 1s.
> Source: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#Description

Do this in your .timer file.

I've struggled with this for quite a while.

Answer (score 3):

Under `[Service]`, add:

```
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
```